# invoke-sql cmdlet/batchparser.dll not being found

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I get the following error when I try and invoke the invoke-sqlcommand cmdlet

> "invoke-sqlcmd : Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser, Version=14.100.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. At line:1 char:1"

I have used import-module SQLServer.
I also have SSMS 2017 on my system as well as Visual Studio 2017
The batchparser.dll IS the correct version and is even in the same directory as the erroneous script and I still get this error.

Even simple commands like : `invoke-sqlcmd -serverinstance 'xxxx' -query "Select @version"` fail.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 2):

I think you have that issue because you run 32-bit PowerShell. Invoke-SqlCmd doesn't support 32-bit at the moment.

- Removed restriction of 64-bit OS for this module. Note: Invoke-Sqlcmd 
  cmdlet is the only cmdlet not supported on 32-bit OS.

source: https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Sqlserver/21.0.17279

Run PowerShell 64-bit and try again.